# SciPy ImportError

Tags: python, scipy, importerror

I have python 3.5, windows 7 64bit.

Installed these wheels whit pip (succesfully? it said so) 
pip is updated

numpy‑1.11.2+mkl‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
scipy‑0.18.1‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl

To check if installed correctly:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/special.html

I used this code.

First line, I get ImportError

"from scipy import special"

What to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, uninstall all python related previous installations. Then install anaconda from here [anaconda's latest version (prefer 32 bit)](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). check "add to path" option in the installation box. Run command prompt as admin and install scipy by   **conda install scipy**
Now run python interpreter from this path "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" and try importing scipy.

Hope this helps